# SQL Server on Kubernetes with replication

Tags: sql-server, docker, kubernetes, minikube, sql-server-2019

I need to deploy SQL Server 2019 on kubernetes with 2 replicas and data synchronization. I'm using minikube, with docker driver. Currently, I managed to deploy two replicas but without data synchronization.

My deploy.yaml file looks like this

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mssql
spec:
  serviceName: mssql
  replicas: 2
  # podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mssql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mssql
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 10001
      containers:
      - name: mssql
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/rhel/server:2019-latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1433
          name: tcpsql
        env:
        - name: MSSQL_ENABLE_HADR
          value: "1"
        - name: MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED
          value: "1"
        - name: ACCEPT_EULA
          value: "Y"
        - name: MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mssql-secret
              key: SA_PASSWORD
        resources:
            requests:
              memory: "4Gi"
              cpu: "2"
            limits:
              memory: "4Gi"
              cpu: "2"
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mssql
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: mssql
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 1433
      targetPort: 1433
      name: tcpsql
```

There were many iterations with multiple .yaml files, but current version works with this one.
With this implementation, I am able to have two instances of sql server, I can connect to one, work on it, in case it gets deleted it will transfer me to the second replica and I can work with it, but the data from the first one will not be there.

I read here of a way to sync database instances for MySQL but unfortunately, I need to use mssql and used tool is not applicable to mssql.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/

This is my first time working with this technology so sorry for patch-like approach on my part. I will provide all the additional info I can.